# VSCodeのターミナルを一行ずつスクロール

Tags: vscode, key-binding

VSCodeのターミナル(Bash)上で一行分だけスクロールしたいと考えております。
一般的に`Shift + ↓ or ↑` で実行できるようなのですが、私の環境ではターミナル上にそれぞれBとAが入力されてしまいます。
下記に添付するキャプチャーのように、キーボードショートカットを見ても、BやAを入力するような設定にはなっていないのですが、この問題を解決して1行だけスクロールする方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

また、`Shift + ← or →`でDやCが入力されてしまいます。これについてもターミナル上で1文字ずつ範囲選択できるように設定できれば幸いです。

実行環境はWindows10 Proです。ご回答何卒宜しくお願い致します。

[image: キーボードショートカット「Shift + Downarrow」]

[image: キーボードショートカット「Shift + Leftarrow」]

Answer (score 2):

cursorLeftSelect等はTerminalと関係ないように思われます。手元のVSCodeでショートカットを`terminal: scroll`で検索してみると、`Ctrl + Shift + ↑/↓`で一行ごとに移動できるようでした。

A,B,C,Dが表示されるのは、シェルのエスケープシーケンスという仕組みにあります。

参考：[Why does the terminal show “^[[A” “^[[B” “^[[C” “^[[D” when pressing the arrow keys in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21384040/3240599)

Comment: @ sei0o 様　早速ご回答いただきありがとございます。`terminal: scroll`で検索したところ、`Ctrl + Alt + PageDown / PageUp`で一行だけスクロールすることができました。おかげさまで大変作業しやすくなりました。　　URL先の回答のコメント欄をみると、ターミナルのモードによって、矢印の入力がそれのエスケープシーケンスでるA,B,C,Dを出力してしまっているようですね。さらに　https://teratail.com/questions/172989　によるとWindows版のVSCodeのターミナルはWinptyに依存していて、これを新しいもの(ConPTY)に変わるまでは対処できないみたいです。（つまりターミナル上で`shift + ←/→`で範囲選択するのはできないみたいです）